# sharing javascript classes between nodejs server and react web client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a few javascript classes that run in my node server that I wish to reuse inside my react web client.  The problem (i think) is that the node code uses *require* and *module.exports* syntax, but the client codebase uses *import* and *export*... and it doesn't look like I can mix the two.

Is there a sensible way to include a few of these server-side classes in my client-side code without duplication?

[EDIT] the issue I'm facing is isolated to reuse of code that contains module.export AND async methods.

Comment: you can use import and export in node too

Comment: You can use `import/export` with node, the problem is that its frustratingly opinionated about how you use it and wants all your JavaScript to have the `.mjs` extension.  [It's also experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).  Are you using webpack or any other bundler?

Comment: Use http://webpack.js.org to bundle your code containing `import/export` into a server and a client bundle.

Comment: I want to use a little server code in the client.  Changing all my server code to .mjs (with import/export) isn't an option at the moment, plus I don't think it would work as react doesn't recognise importing mjs files.

Answer (score 1):

CommonJS modules and `module.export` are common denominator between Node.js and React client-side application.

Since React application is expected to be built with transpiler (Babel) and bundling tool (Webpack), both ES and CommonJS modules can be handled by Webpack. Shared CommonJS module can be `import`ed in client-side ES modules. They won't have benefits of ES modules this way, notably tree-shaking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't understand what you're saying.  I simply don't appear to be able to use a class written for node (with module.export) inside a react app.  It just doesn't compile.

Comment: You should be able to import them as usual modules. What do 'don't appear to be able' and ' doesn't compile' mean? Are you getting error messages? The question doesn't say anything about the problem.

Comment: Hmm, it started working. I was getting a bunch of errors when I first tried to symlink a directory containing the node code so that it appeared in my react src.  However, when I tried again, but just with one or two files it worked.  I guess one of the files in the directory contained something react didn't like (sorry, I don't have the error any more).  In summary, you can add old-style node code to a react source tree.

Comment: @pomo *In summary, you can add old-style node code to a react source tree.* - that's correct. A lot of third-party libraries you're using from NPM are used as CommonJS (Node style) modules. Shouldn't be a problem when your app is bundled with Webpack/Rollup/etc.

Comment: Right, I finally got back to the original error.  First of all you can't use async in the code that has model.exports for some reason.  After removing all of those I get "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object", which  I discussed here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039

Comment: *First of all you can't use async in the code that has model.exports for some reason* - this may depend on how you use it, I guess. Notice that Babel `modules: false` config is suggested in the issue you've linked. I'd expect it to be needed. The problem is specific to your setup, while you asked the question in general. In general, there's no problem in reusing CJS module between server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

If your node version does not support import export, you can check babel to convert it into desired ES version. Check [this example](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server)

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried, but as soon as I did I got an error relating to my use of async await.  After about an hour or two of babel hell I gave up.